# Calculating the area of a shapefile with multiple features using the field calculator, gives "nan"

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I've created a shapefile with multiple features, and want to calculate the area in acres of 3 polygons. The shapefile is in the right CRS, when I open the attribute table and start an edit mode, open the field calculator, create a new field "Area", select the type "decimal number real", the output fields are good with 10 and 3, select Geometry, `$area` it doesn't calculate the area in acres. It gives me "nan" in the preview.

What is my problem?

I'm running QGIS 3.28.3.

Comment: Difficult to say without further context. Can you share your data (at least a sample)?

Comment: Did you actually run the calculation? Which CRS is the data in?